# There is a conflict when executing 'openni.launch' and 'amcl_demo.launch' in separate terminals

Tags: navigation, camera, driver, ros, kinect

I am using ROS Noetic with an Xbox 360 Kinect camera, and I need to use the camera while the robot is moving in a saved map. Initially, I run the command `$ roslaunch turtlebot_navigation amcl_demo.launch map_file:=/tmp/my_map.yaml`, and everything works well. However, when I run the OpenNI driver using the command `$ roslaunch openni_launch openni.launch`, an error occurs.

-Note that everything works fine individually.
-[The screenshot contains the error massage.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/U26HC.jpg)

This is amcl_demo.launch file

```
<launch>
  <!-- 3D sensor -->
  <arg name="3d_sensor" default="$(env TURTLEBOT_3D_SENSOR)"/>  <!-- r200, kinect, asus_xtion_pro -->
  <include file="$(find turtlebot_bringup)/launch/3dsensor.launch">
    <arg name="rgb_processing" value="false" />
    <arg name="depth_registration" value="false" />
    <arg name="depth_processing" value="false" />
    
    <!-- We must specify an absolute topic name because if not it will be prefixed by "$(arg camera)".
         Probably is a bug in the nodelet manager: https://github.com/ros/nodelet_core/issues/7 --> 
    <arg name="scan_topic" value="/scan" />
  </include>

  <!-- Map server -->
  <arg name="map_file" default="$(env TURTLEBOT_MAP_FILE)"/>
  <node name="map_server" pkg="map_server" type="map_server" args="$(arg map_file)" />

  <!-- AMCL -->
  <arg name="custom_amcl_launch_file" default="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/includes/amcl/$(arg 3d_sensor)_amcl.launch.xml"/>
  <arg name="initial_pose_x" default="0.0"/> <!-- Use 17.0 for willow's map in simulation -->
  <arg name="initial_pose_y" default="0.0"/> <!-- Use 17.0 for willow's map in simulation -->
  <arg name="initial_pose_a" default="0.0"/>
  <include file="$(arg custom_amcl_launch_file)">
    <arg name="initial_pose_x" value="$(arg initial_pose_x)"/>
    <arg name="initial_pose_y" value="$(arg initial_pose_y)"/>
    <arg name="initial_pose_a" value="$(arg initial_pose_a)"/>
  </include>

  <!-- Move base -->
  <arg name="custom_param_file" default="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/param/$(arg 3d_sensor)_costmap_params.yaml"/>
  <include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/includes/move_base.launch.xml">
    <arg name="custom_param_file" value="$(arg custom_param_file)"/>
  </include>

</launch>
```

And this is openni_launch file

```
<!-- Entry point for using OpenNI devices -->
<launch>

  <!-- "camera" should uniquely identify the device. All topics are pushed down
       into the "camera" namespace, and it is prepended to tf frame ids. -->
  <arg name="camera" default="camera" />
  <arg name="rgb_frame_id"   default="$(arg camera)_rgb_optical_frame" />
  <arg name="depth_frame_id" default="$(arg camera)_depth_optical_frame" />

  <!-- device_id can have the following formats:
         "B00367707227042B": Use device with given serial number
         "#1"              : Use first device found
         "2@3"             : Use device on USB bus 2, address 3
         "2@0"             : Use first device found on USB bus 2
    -->
  <arg name="device_id" default="#2" />

  <!-- By default, calibrations are stored to file://${ROS_HOME}/camera_info/${NAME}.yaml,
       where ${NAME} is of the form "[rgb|depth]_[serial#]", e.g. "depth_B00367707227042B".
       See camera_info_manager docs for calibration URL details. -->
  <arg name="rgb_camera_info_url"   default="" />
  <arg name="depth_camera_info_url" default="" />

  <!-- Use OpenNI's factory-calibrated depth->RGB registration? -->
  <arg name="depth_registration" default="false" />

  <!-- Arguments for remapping all device namespaces -->
  <arg name="rgb"                       default="rgb" />
  <arg name="ir"                        default="ir" />
  <arg name="depth"                     default="depth" />
  <arg name="depth_registered"          default="depth_registered" />
  <arg name="depth_registered_filtered" default="depth_registered" />
  <arg name="projector"                 default="projector" />

  <!-- Optionally suppress loading the driver nodelet and/or publishing the default tf
       tree. Useful if you are playing back recorded raw data from a bag, or are
       supplying a more accurate tf tree from calibration. -->
  <arg name="load_driver" default="true" />
  <arg name="publish_tf" default="true" />
  <!-- Processing Modules -->
  <arg name="rgb_processing"                  default="true"/>
  <arg name="ir_processing"                   default="true"/>
  <arg name="depth_processing"                default="true"/>
  <arg name="depth_registered_processing"     default="true"/>
  <arg name="disparity_processing"            default="true"/>
  <arg name="disparity_registered_processing" default="true"/>
  <arg name="hw_registered_processing"        default="true" />
  <arg name="sw_registered_processing"        default="true" />

  <!-- Disable bond topics by default -->
  <arg name="bond" default="false" /> <!-- DEPRECATED, use respawn arg instead -->
  <arg name="respawn" default="$(arg bond)" />

  <!-- Worker threads for the nodelet manager -->
  <arg name="num_worker_threads" default="4" />

  <!-- Push down all topics/nodelets into "camera" namespace -->
  <group ns="$(arg camera)">
  
    <!-- Start nodelet manager in top-level namespace -->
    <arg name="manager" value="$(arg camera)_nodelet_manager" />
    <arg name="debug" default="false" /> <!-- Run manager in GDB? -->
    <include file="$(find rgbd_launch)/launch/includes/manager.launch.xml">
      <arg name="name"                value="$(arg manager)" />
      <arg name="debug"               value="$(arg debug)" />
      <arg name="num_worker_threads"  value="$(arg num_worker_threads)" />
    </include>

    <!-- Load driver -->
    <include if="$(arg load_driver)"
         file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/includes/device.launch.xml">
      <!-- Could really use some syntactic sugar for this -->
      <arg name="manager"               value="$(arg manager)" />
      <arg name="device_id"             value="$(arg device_id)" />
      <arg name="rgb_frame_id"          value="$(arg rgb_frame_id)" />
      <arg name="depth_frame_id"        value="$(arg depth_frame_id)" />
      <arg name="rgb_camera_info_url"   value="$(arg rgb_camera_info_url)" />
      <arg name="depth_camera_info_url" value="$(arg depth_camera_info_url)" />
      <arg name="depth_registration"    value="$(arg depth_registration)" />
      <arg name="rgb"                   value="$(arg rgb)" />
      <arg name="ir"                    value="$(arg ir)" />
      <arg name="depth"                 value="$(arg depth)" />
      <arg name="depth_registered"      value="$(arg depth_registered)" />
      <arg name="projector"             value="$(arg projector)" />
      <arg name="respawn"               value="$(arg respawn)" />
    </include>
    
    <!-- Load standard constellation of processing nodelets -->
    <include file="$(find rgbd_launch)/launch/includes/processing.launch.xml">
      <arg name="manager"                         value="$(arg manager)" />
      <arg name="rgb"                             value="$(arg rgb)" />
      <arg name="ir"                              value="$(arg ir)" />
      <arg name="depth"                           value="$(arg depth)" />
      <arg name="depth_registered"                value="$(arg depth_registered)" />
      <arg name="depth_registered_filtered"       value="$(arg depth_registered_filtered)" />
      <arg name="projector"                       value="$(arg projector)" />
      <arg name="respawn"                         value="$(arg respawn)" />
      <arg name="rgb_processing"                  value="$(arg rgb_processing)" />
      <arg name="ir_processing"                   value="$(arg ir_processing)" />
      <arg name="depth_processing"                value="$(arg depth_processing)" />
      <arg name="depth_registered_processing"     value="$(arg depth_registered_processing)" />
      <arg name="disparity_processing"            value="$(arg disparity_processing)" />
      <arg name="disparity_registered_processing" value="$(arg disparity_registered_processing)" />
      <arg name="hw_registered_processing"        value="$(arg hw_registered_processing)" />
      <arg name="sw_registered_processing"        value="$(arg sw_registered_processing)" />
    </include>
  
  </group> <!-- camera -->

  <!-- Load reasonable defaults for the relative pose between cameras -->
  <include if="$(arg publish_tf)"
       file="$(find rgbd_launch)/launch/kinect_frames.launch">
    <arg name="camera" value="$(arg camera)" />
  </include>

</launch>
```

I tried to create a combined_launch file but the same error occurs
this is the combined_launch file

```
<launch>
    <!-- Launch the OpenNI driver -->
    <include file="$(find openni_launch)/launch/openni.launch">
        <arg name="camera" default="camera" />
    </include>

    <!-- Wait for a few seconds to ensure the camera is up and running -->
    <rosparam command="load" file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/maps/wait_for_camera.yaml" />

    <!-- Launch the TurtleBot navigation -->
    <include file="$(find turtlebot_navigation)/launch/amcl_demo.launch">
        <arg name="map_file" value="/home/raghad/ppu_map.yaml" />
    </include>
</launch>
```